# How to add Facebook Like Button in desktop application?

Tags: vb.net, web, facebook-like

I would like to know how to add Like button in VB.NET winforms application.
I created index.html which include iframe to call Facebook Like Button
Now I used WebBrowser Control to show Facebook Like Button.
It appear in my form and can login with Facebook account the problem is Like Count is not increase, please help me!!!

This is sample code I used

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F    %2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fchequeprintingsoftware&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&    amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&    amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>



</body>
</html>
```

VB.NET

```
Private Sub frmFaceBookLike_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim html As String
        html = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\index.html")
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = html
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Like button was designed for use in web environments - you know, the page is hosted on a server, Facebook can scrape the URL, and so on. The way you've implemented the Like button is rather innovative - but ultimately, it won't really work, as you can see - in your case, the count isn't increasing.

A better solution, is to use the Open Graph, and have your own implementation of the Like button. In such a scenario, you'd use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/), and use the Like action provided by the Open Graph, to create your own Like button. You can find more details about the Open Graph's Like action [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/).

Comment: There's one thing you must note, though - this Open Graph action doesn't automatically display the likes count. You may have to do a separate API call for that, and display it separately.

Comment: I didn't get your point because my skill is very weak. So can I get sample code for this. I already C# SDK, it is only support for Window 8 desktop application, right? So how to create my own like button? Please help me, I'll waiting your reply.

Comment: Okay, so the C# SDK supports more than just Windows 8 apps - it supports Windows Forms, ASP.NET, Silverlight and Windows Phone. As of now, there are no such samples - but I guess I could write a code sample in a day or two.